# height not being set unless I "inspect page"

Tags: jquery, html, resize, height

For some reason this works when the page first loads and when the content gets resized it will only run the "matchColumns" if I do an "inspect element" in chrome.  Can't seem to understand why it does that instead of changing everytime the content changes.  [Here](http://inblu.pe/el/) is the site that I am working with.  Thanks in advance.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    MC.general.init();
    MC.homeSlider.init();
    MC.homeMap.init();
    $j(window).resize(function() {
      $j('#layer-base, #layer-top, .exposed, ').matchColumns();
    }); 
});

$j.fn.matchColumns = function(){
    var height_tar = $j(document).height();
    $j(this).css({"height": (height_tar ) + "px"});
}; // matchColumns
```

Comment: it seems to work for me, however I only tried adding a breakpoint in side `matchColumns()` are you sure it's not working but the desired effect isn't occurring? Have you tried adding something like `consonle.log('matchColumns ran');` to make sure?

Comment: If you want to check each time the content changes, you should bind to the `change` event. Resize is... well - resize, when the browser window changes size

Comment: I think this has more to do with using `$(document).height()` rather than perhaps `$(window).height()`, the document height isn't going to change on resize as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I put an alert after the "height_tar" is set and it stays on 643 unless I open up in Chrome the Inspect Element then it changes to 840 when the right content is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting opens the Web Inspector in Chrome/Safari or Firebug in Firefox, which takes up some portion of the viewport and triggers a window resize event (even though the window hasn't changed size as far as the OS is concerned, from your document's point of view it has).

I'd add a call to matchColumns that runs right away, in addition to the calls that fire on resize. So like:

```
$j(window).resize(function() {
  $j('#layer-base, #layer-top, .exposed, ').matchColumns();
}); 
$j('#layer-base, #layer-top, .exposed, ').matchColumns();
```

Or better, factor out that line into a function.